# Вконтакте перестал воспринимать сертификат что делать?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Vk CallBack API начал писать вот такое:

> Error: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates

Раньше работало нормально.

Переехал на новый сервер (отдельный). Там стоит ISP Manager. Перевыпустил сертификат безопасности Comodo Positive SSL.

При заходе на домен, сертификат показывается и замочек висит, что безопасное соединение.

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил сам...

Нужно было указать цепочку сертификатов в ISP manager.

При добавлении сертификата нужно указать

1) SSL-сертификат - Сертификат присланный в письме (фал названный вашим доменым именем)

2) Ключ SSL-сертификата - Приватный ключ, полученный при запросе сертификата.

3) Цепочка SSL-сертификатов - Цепочку сертификатов от COMODO в поле в таком порядке вставить в поле:

```
COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA
COMODORSAAddTrustCA
```

просто откройте файлы в Блокноте скопируйте код, и попорядку вставьте.